# Migrate jquery slick carousel to vue-slick-carousel

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page having a carousel implemented using slick-carousel and jquery but I'm building this page in vue. Everything else works while migrating this carousel from jquery to vue except for the image itself which doesn't show up. I've been hacking at this for about three hours with no luck.

Heres the code for the carousel:

Jquery:

```
<div class=" petmark-slick-slider  home-slider" data-slick-setting='{
                                                "autoplay": true,
                                                "autoplaySpeed": 8000,
                                                "slidesToShow": 1,
                                                "dots": true
                                        }'>
                            <div class="single-slider home-content bg-image" data-bg="image/slider-2.jpg">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                                            <h2> <span class="text-primary">61+ </span> Blood test<br> package</h2>

                                            <h4 class="mt--30">package just Rs 399</h4>

                                            <div class="slider-btn mt--30">
                                                <a href="shop.html" class="btn btn-outlined--white btn-rounded">Book Now</a>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <span class="herobanner-progress"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="single-slider home-content bg-image" data-bg="image/slider-1.jpg">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                                            <h2> <span class="text-primary">Flat </span> 20% <br> off</h2>

                                            <h4 class="mt--30">on all online bookings</h4>

                                            <div class="slider-btn mt--30">
                                                <a href="shop.html" class="btn btn-outlined--white btn-rounded">Book Now</a>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <span class="herobanner-progress"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Vue:

In template

```
<VueSlickCarousel class="petmark-slick-slider home-slider" :dots="true" :autoplay="true" :autoplaySpeed="8000" :slidesToShow="1">
                            <div class="single-slider home-content bg-image" data-bg="image/slider-2.jpg">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                                            <h2> <span class="text-primary">61+ </span> Blood test<br> package</h2>

                                            <h4 class="mt--30">package just Rs 399</h4>

                                            <div class="slider-btn mt--30">
                                                <a href="shop.html" class="btn btn-outlined--white btn-rounded">Book Now</a>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <span class="herobanner-progress"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="single-slider home-content bg-image" data-bg="image/slider-1.jpg">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                                            <h2> <span class="text-primary">Flat </span> 20% <br> off</h2>

                                            <h4 class="mt--30">on all online bookings</h4>

                                            <div class="slider-btn mt--30">
                                                <a href="shop.html" class="btn btn-outlined--white btn-rounded">Book Now</a>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <span class="herobanner-progress"></span>
                            </div>
                        </VueSlickCarousel>
```

In script

```
import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'

    export default {
        name: 'Home',
        components: { VueSlickCarousel }
    }
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another question that solved this. Basically just change the code as follows:

```
<VueSlickCarousel class="petmark-slick-slider home-slider" :dots="true" :autoplay="true" :autoplaySpeed="8000" :slidesToShow="1">
                            <div class="single-slider home-content bg-image" v-bind:style="{'backgroundImage': 'url(\'image/slider-2.jpg\')'}">
...
...
```